# Remap <ENTER> so it makes new line and insert a datestamp

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, abbreviations

I'm making a program for taking statistics during sports, where I script the games. I'm would like to make a VIM shortcut/remap, so every time I press  that it does exactly what the ENTER-key normally does, but that it simply inserts a timestamp as well (and it should only be done in Insert-mode).

My thinking was, that I then could go into my VIMRC-file and activate the shortcut, whenever I was doing statistics.

Here's what I've tried:

```
 iabbrev <CR> <CR>:put =strftime('%H%M%S')^
```

The '^' in the end is there in the end, because when you insert the timestamp with :put =strftime('....'), that the cursor then is a the beginning of the newly inserted timestamp. But nothing happens with this in my VIMRC-file.

I've also tried:

```
iabbrev <ENTER> <ENTER>:put =strftime('%H%M%S')<CR>
```

And still, nothing happens.

I've even tried this, to try and see, if I could just make VIM insert any character, whenever I hit ENTER, but this doesn't do anything either:

```
 iabbrev <CR> <CR>1
```

I apologies, if this is a stupid question.

EXAMPLE OF USE:

Let's say that I was typing this on the keyboard:

```
upthrtwo
ussevfiv
tptwothr
uhsevtwo
```

Then I wanted VIM to have written this:

```
151852upthrtwo
151907ussevfiv
151917tptwothr
151949uhsevtwo
```

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following

`:inoremap <CR> <Esc>:put =strftime('%H%M%S')<CR>A`

This will map your enter key when in insert mode (`inoremap`) so that

- It exits to command mode (`<Esc>`)
- It runs `:put =strftime('%H%M%S')`, which inserts a newline and writes your timestamp to the new line (also note the `<CR>` at the end to execut the comamnd)
- It puts you back in insert mode at the end of the new line with `A`

Comment: It works. When I enable it, then it works all fine and dandy. But when I comment it out in the VIMRC, then it keeps inserting the timestamp (probably because there's no active command that says 'THE ENTER KEY IS THE ENTER KEY'. So when I comment it out in my VIMRC-file, then I just have to add the line>> 
:inoremap <CR> <CR>
Whereafter the ENTER-key functions normally again.